# I am having trouble to find good initial shoots for fitting oscillatory function with lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

The problem I am solving consists of fitting the parameters of a coupled Van der Pol oscillator, as reported in the quoted paper [link to paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.08886). Instead of using the adjoint method the authors proposed, I wanted to give it a try on classical Least-Squares. For this purpose, I decided to "validate" with a "synthetic" case. Let me share an excerpt of this part

**Residual definition**

```
def residual_ode(params,t,data,ID,theta,sol_0):
    """
    Here I define the residual function to minimize.
    """
    A,B,D           = params[ID[0]],params[ID[1]],params[ID[2]]
    c_til,d_len,x_0 = theta
    u0              = ode_solver(A,B,D,sol_0,t)[0]
    
    #plt.plot(t, u0, 'g-')
    
    return u0 - data
```

**And the ODEs' solver**

```
def ode_sys(sol,t,A,B,D):
    """
    This function returns the order reduction for the Van der Pol's ODEs
    A , B, D: are scalar parameters to be "determined"
    x_sol , y_sol: are displacements
    u_sol , v_sol: are velocities
    You need to convert the 2-second order ODEs into 4-first order ODEs
    """
    
    x_sol , u_sol , y_sol , v_sol = sol
    
    x_der = u_sol
    u_der = (A - B * (1 + np.power(x_sol,2))) * u_sol + (0.5 *D-1) * x_sol + A * v_sol
    y_der = v_sol
    v_der = (A - B * (1 + np.power(y_sol,2))) * v_sol - (0.5 *D+1) * y_sol + A * u_sol
    
    return [x_der,u_der,y_der,v_der]

def ode_solver(A,B,D,sol_0,t):
    """
    This function integrates the coupled ODEs that represent the Van der Pol oscillators
    A     :: alpha
    B     :: beta
    D     :: delta
    sol_0 :: initial condition [x(0),x'(0),y(0),y'(0)]
    t     :: time array
    u0    :: computed glottal flow
    sol   :: displacements of both vocal folds vs time
    """
    # Here I define constants of the model (physiological props.)
    c_til = 50            # air particle velocity, m/s
    d_len = 0.0175        # length of vocal folds, m
    x_0   = 0.001         # half glottal width at rest position, m
    
    sol   = odeint(ode_sys,sol_0,t,args=(A,B,D))
    u0    = c_til * d_len * (2 * x_0 + sol[:,0] + sol[:,2])
    
    return u0,sol
```

**Step 1, define constants and fixed parameters:**

```
# Here I define constants of the model
c_til = 50            # air particle velocity, m/s
d_len = 0.0175        # length of vocal folds, m
x_0   = 0.001         # half glottal width at rest position, m
sol_0 = [0,0.1,0,0.1] # Initial state from papers (reference) (x(0),x'(0),y(0),y'(0))
theta = [c_til,d_len,x_0]

if(dataset == 'Synthetic'):
    # Here I define a synthetic dataset just to test the fit
    A     = 0.50 # Reference value
    B     = 0.32 # Reference value
    D     = 0.00 # Reference value

    t     = np.linspace(0,60*pi,1000)
    data , tgt = ode_solver(A,B,D,sol_0,t)
    data  = data + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=t.shape) # Add a noise to see the robustness.
else:
    # Here I upload a given audio file
    t, signal , glot_flow, sr = load_audio('target.WAV')
    t    = t[:900]
    data = glot_flow[:900] * 1.0e-01
else:
    # Here I upload a given audio file
    t, signal , glot_flow, sr = load_audio('target.WAV')
    t    = t[:900]
    data = glot_flow[:900] * 1.0e-01
```

**Step 2, declare the parameters to fit, plus the min-max limits and other props.**

```
# Define the initial shoot and ranges for the parameters to fit
ID = ['A' ,'B' ,'D']
if(dataset == 'Synthetic'):
    i0 = [0.50,0.50,0.50] # This one works for synthetic
else:
    i0 = [0.50,0.50,0.50]

vi , vf = [0,0,0] , [1,1,1] # According to code, they are always between (0,1)
```

**Step 3, Define and call the lmfit minimizer stuff**

```
# According to lmfit, you must define ranges for parameters and initial guess
params = lmf.Parameters()
params.add(ID[0],value=i0[0], min=vi[0], max=vf[0])  # alpha
params.add(ID[1],value=i0[1], min=vi[1], max=vf[1])  # beta
params.add(ID[2],value=i0[2], min=vi[2], max=vf[2])  # Delta

# lmfit minimizer 
foo = lmf.Minimizer(residual_ode, params,fcn_kws={'t': t, 'data':data,'ID':ID, 'theta':theta, 'sol_0':sol_0})

result = foo.minimize(method='leastsq')
lmf.report_fit(result)
```

As mentioned before I validate the fitting script with synthetic data. The lmfit report shows very nice results, with *low variability*,

```
Fitting ODEs running on lmfit v1.0.0
Analyzed dataset Synthetic
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 101
    # data points      = 1000
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 9.96375601
    reduced chi-square = 0.00999374
    Akaike info crit   = -4602.80117
    Bayesian info crit = -4588.07790
[[Variables]]
    A:  0.50089718 +/- 1.5368e-07 (0.00%) (init = 0.5)
    B:  0.32140460 +/- 2.1184e-05 (0.01%) (init = 0.5)
    D:  0.02961727 +/- 4.6440e-05 (0.16%) (init = 0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(B, D) = -0.857
    C(A, B) =  0.644
    C(A, D) = -0.373
```

Motivated by these GOOD results I decided to move forward to a "realistic" case, please have a look at the fitness report:

```
Fitting ODEs running on lmfit v1.0.0
Analyzed dataset real
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 41
    # data points      = 900
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.98750335
    reduced chi-square = 0.00110090
    Akaike info crit   = -6127.47314
    Bayesian info crit = -6113.06595
[[Variables]]
    A:  3.6795e-06 +/- 51769552.4 (1406957752181724.50%) (init = 0.5)
    B:  0.99999944 +/- 2.6702e+08 (26701595662.24%) (init = 0.5)
    D:  0.21433002 +/- 2.4401e+11 (113848637625094.62%) (init = 0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(A, B) =  1.000
    C(B, D) = -0.964
```

Unfortunately, there is a LOT of variabilities here. Let me also share some figures that illustrate the problem. [image: The synthetic GOOD case], [image: The realistic UGLY case].

Comment: In the two plots you show, the time scale - and so the period of the oscillations - differ by about 3 orders of magnitude.   It is a little hard for me to guess what impact that will have on your parameters "A", "B", and "D", but it sure seems like the velocities must have very different scales. so: a) relax the bounds on your parameters, and b) test your model function by calling it with realistic values and seeing if it close to your data.  I guess that the scaling difference between your "synthetic"  and "realistic" data is causing your parameter ranges to be different.

Comment: Note that the standard VanderPol oscillator `x''+mu*(x^2-rho)*x'+x=0  <=> x''+mu*(x^2+1)*x'+x=mu*(1+rho)*x'` has for small `mu=B, A=0.5*(1+rho)*mu` a frequency of 1 with a period length `T` of `2*pi~6.3` and amplitude `R=2*rho**0.5`, T and R slightly increasing with `mu`. This is present in your first test data set where you get about 16 oscillations on a length of 100 and amplitude of about `4`. Depending on how you count, the second data set has 1 or 2 oscillations on a length of 0.01. To tune for this you need to either re-scale the time manually, or allow for a variable frequency.

Comment: Is there an alternative source for a sample of test data, the conference web site has this part no longer present.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, let me ask/answer by parts. How can I  re-scale the time? How can I add a new fit param. to adjust the freqs.? On a second part, I can share "privately" an audio file... And the library I am using to get glottal flow...

Comment: You can do a frequency analysis on the signal, and then rescale the time line so that the dominating frequency gets mapped to 1. The other variant is to provide the underived term with a coefficient, so that you get `x''+B*(1+x^2)*x'+C*x=...` If there is no public source, then the processed data series that you used to draw the dots in the second graph is sufficient to make proof-of-concept examples that the model is good enough for the data. Which is not really in question as the paper already proved that.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, OK, will try both alternatives. I've been asking about the adjoint solver to "follow to the word" the paper.... If that solves, I'm very happy. If not I'll try to get improvements here with `lmfit`, and classic least-squares... In any case I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I'm not sure how that section got through the review. Computing sensitivities in an AD backwards sweep is something that was systematically done since the 1960s, I'm sure one could find traces of that in Gauß' Ceres computation and perhaps also in Newton's work. Computing adjoints for a differential equation is a standard technique in optimal control theory, methods to do it fast and with narrow memory are also well-investigated. So we have a process that goes from small data to large data to an error functional and got a gradient of it, and then the paper stops mentioning gradient descent...

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I agree with you. The paper should have been focused on the last part. Mapping the results of the fitness (alpha, beta, delta) with healthy/un-healthy features...

Comment: @LutzLehmann by chance do you know a way to study the stability of the two coupled (quasi) Van der Pol oscillators??? I took the jacobian matrix and evaluate inthe critical points....but in many cases I get one pair of eigenvalues stable and the other pair un stable... what does this means in the Iver all solution???

Comment: The combination of stretching, compressing and mixing leads to chaotic behavior. This might me constrained to a torus around some closed orbit, or totally free-form. The discussion of the bifurcation diagram in the paper had examples. You could also compute Lyapunov exponents along a solution to see if this behavior of the stationary points gives also the global picture.

Comment: @LutzLehmann a practical way could be "check how the amplitude changes after several periods" ??? Erratic evolution of the solution is un stable.... what do you think?